# Full HTML Block displaying incorrectly to Anonymous

Tags: 7, blocks

I have been looking for help on this issue for awhile, but I can't seem to crack it. 
For some reason, I need to have "Bypass content access control"  enabled to get this to look correctly.

I may be doing it wrong, so I'll let you know about what I'm trying to do as well. I want to make a Bootstrap Carousel that shows the images,  exactly as you see in the preview image.

What I've done is made a full-HTML block and pasted the code directly in to that. It works perfectly as the administrator, but it isn't working correctly with the DOM, obviously, as anonymous.

I've found things in the past where people had problems with this same permission, but nothing from 2013 to now. And as far as I can tell, nothing with the way blocks were rendered.

The site where you can see how it is actually working is: [dev.americasconference.org](http://dev.americasconference.org)
[image]

The way this should be working is that they previous/next flaps should be overlays on the photos, and not over the left and right margins of the web page.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Seems to me that this is just a css issue: to get the pager to overlay the image, just add div#myCarousel { position: relative;}. As an aside, your images are large (1753x739), and take a while to load: consider using an image style to resize them to the max displayed size :)

Comment: You were absolutely right on all accounts. The images are enormous and having my browser cache disabled, I sit through the loading process on each load, but I was too concerned about whether or not I'd be able to use this carousel implementation at all.

So, while what you say is correct - it was a css issue. Why do you suppose it works for the administrator account and not the anonymous account? Also, the only way I was able to get the style to stick was to use it as a one-off 'style="position:relative;"' comment within the div tag. 

Again, many thanks for this, you really saved me!

Comment: My pleasure. :) If the markup is different for logged-in users, that does suggest some kind of permission issue. I don't know which one, though. If you write CSS in your theme and it doesn't have any effect, that's ether because the CSS file hasn't been registered in the theme's .info file, or because you haven't cleared the caches, or because there's a more specific CSS rule somewhere trumping yours.